# scrapy spider code check

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

so im' trying to scrape the website in the SgmlLinkExtractor parameters below website with scrapy, and this is what my spider looks like:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from desidime_sample.items import DesidimeItem
import string

class DesidimeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "desidime"
    allowed_domains = ["desidime.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.desidime.com/forums/hot-deals-online"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('''//td[not(@*)]/div
        [not(@*)]/a[not(@class)]/@href''')), callback="parse_items", follow=True),
)
    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        deals = hxs.select('''//div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]''')
        items = []
        for deals in deals:
            item = DesidimeItem()
            item["deal"]  = deals.select("//div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]/p/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = deals.select("//div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]/p[1]/a[1]/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

It should be quite obvious what I'm *trying* to do, but for some reason when I tell the spider to crawl and export the text and links to the CVS file, I end up with:

> link,deal http://wwww.facebook.com/desidime,
>   http://wwww.facebook.com/desidime,
>   (same thing for many more lines, then:)
>   ",,"
>   , " same url" ,
>   (same thing for many more lines, then:)
>   "link,deals"

So, can anyone tell me what the problem is?  If you run each of my above xpaths as `reponse.xpath("xpath").extract()` after `scrapy shell "//corresponingcrawlruleurl"`, you'll get the right results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside the `parse_items` callback. When you iterate over the deals, the deal context-specific locators have to be relative. In other words, start your XPath expressions inside the loop with a dot:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    for deal in response.xpath("//div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]"):
        item = DesidimeItem()

        item["deal"]  = deal.xpath(".//p/text()").extract()
        item["link"] = deal.xpath(".//p[1]/a[1]/@href").extract()

        yield item
```

(note that I've also simplified the code).

Here is the complete spider, I'm executing (it does scrape the text and links, though I don't know what is your desired output):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class DesidimeItem(scrapy.Item):
    deal = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()


class DesidimeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "desidime"
    allowed_domains = ["desidime.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.desidime.com/forums/hot-deals-online"]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//td[not(@*)]/div[not(@*)]/a[not(@class)]"),
             callback="parse_items",
             follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        for deal in response.xpath("//div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]"):
            item = DesidimeItem()

            item["deal"] = deal.xpath(".//p/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = deal.xpath(".//p[1]/a[1]/@href").extract()

            yield item
```

Comment: I thought "//" WAS relative to the path in 'response.xpath()? also do I still need './/div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]' in the xpath fo item["deal"] and item["link"]?

Comment: @user3108815 you definitely need the dot. And yes, I've removed the `//div[@class='user-comment-text'][1]` also. Note that I have not tested the provided code - it's just coming from the experience. Hope it helps.

Comment: quick question: what if i want to only take the text that comes before "PC" on this page [link](http://www.desidime.com/forums/hot-deals-online/topics/deal-of-the-day-philips-gc2840-2200-watt-steam-iron-rs-2199-37-off?f=1) for example? the stuff that comes after pc is useless for any deals page i crawl. how would I format the xpath for item["deal"]?

Comment: @user3108815 I think I'll need to execute and test the spider. Hope will take a look later. Thanks.

Comment: @user3108815 I've updated the code and provided the spider that I'm executing. The extracted data might not be what you exactly want (you may need to tweak the spider or locators), but there is no problem described in the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91949/discussion-between-user3108815-and-alecxe).